Compose Multiplatform onKeyEvent not registering
I am trying to utlise the onKeyEvent for a multuplatform desktop application to register onKeyEvents for the Left and Right arrow keys. My intention is to listen for when the left or right arrow key is pressed and move the spaceship accordingly.
on the spaceship image I have added a modifier which listens to onKeyEvents but nothing registers. It seems it never runs the block of code checking for which Key was pressed and nothing happens, it does not print anythin from my doSomething() function. Please help me solve what I am doing wrong.
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.focusRequester
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.key.*
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import org.jetbrains.compose.resources.ExperimentalResourceApi
import org.jetbrains.compose.resources.painterResource
import org.jetbrains.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

import spaceinvaders.composeapp.generated.resources.Res
import spaceinvaders.composeapp.generated.resources.Space_Invaders_Logo
import spaceinvaders.composeapp.generated.resources.Spaceship

@OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black))
        var showContent by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        if (showContent) {
            AnimatedVisibility(showContent) {
                Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    Image(
                        painterResource(Res.drawable.Space_Invaders_Logo),
                        null,
                    )

                    Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                        Button(onClick = { showContent = !showContent }) {
                            Text("PLAY")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

            Row(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom) {
                Image(
                    painterResource(Res.drawable.Spaceship),
                    null,
                    Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester).onKeyEvent { event: KeyEvent ->
                        when(event.key) {
                            Key.DirectionLeft -> {
                                doSomething()
                                true
                            }

                            else -> {
                                true
                            }
                        }

                    }.focusable()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

fun doSomething() {
    println("left key pressed")
}

I have tried the above code but nothing seems to register. I am unsure why they are not registering.
Thank you for the help.

have you checked this answer? you seems to be missing requestFocus call

Ahhh you're a genius. Thank you very much. I did see that comment but I did not know that I had to use LaunchedEffect to call on the focused object.
